# Not able to fetch custom field and Profile fields in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am not able to get `User.Profile.Name` and `Case.Swap_Type__c` field value but I am getting other field values.

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord,getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email';
import PROFILE_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Profile.Name';
import ORIGIN_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Origin';
import SWAP_TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Swap_Type__c';

export default class CmpSelectAssetComponent extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track prfName;
    @track swapType;

    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: USER_ID,
        fields: [EMAIL_FIELD,PROFILE_NAME_FIELD]
    }) wireuser({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (error) {
           this.error = error ; 
        } else if (data) {
            this.email = data.fields.Email.value;
            this.prfName = data.fields.Profile.Name.value;         
        }
    }

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ORIGIN_FIELD,SWAP_TYPE_FIELD] })
    record;

    get originValue() {
        return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, ORIGIN_FIELD) : '';
    }
    get swapType() {
        return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, SWAP_TYPE_FIELD) : '';        
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: did you inspect `data.fields` value? are you sure you are referencing Profile correctly, for example, that it is not profile__r ?

Comment: I believe I am referencing Profile correctly since Profile is a standard object and a parent of user , it should be referenced `User.Profile.Name`

Comment: double check the `data.fields` value being returned

Comment: I'll debug `data.fields`. I also have issues with `import SWAP_TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Swap_Type__c';` . Do you think if syntax used here is not correct assuming `Case.Swap_Type__c` is referenced properly.

Comment: You might also need to double check that the user that is accessing those values have the proper access rights set up. LDS follows field-level security and sharing settings.

Comment: I have inspected `data.fields.Profile.value` and am getting `Id,Name`. but when I use `data.fields.Profile.Name.value` it results in `undefined`. I have added debug image in question.

Comment: `data.fields.Profile.value.fields.Name.value` this is how I am getting profile name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data.fields.Profile.value.fields.Name.value` ---  this gives profile name of logged in user.

Comment: I am getting FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Invalid reference User.Profile.Name of type sobjectField in file though I am a system admin

Comment: Are you able to fetch any details of User.Profile

Comment: No, I guess in summer 19 we have a similar issue with lightning component where if we are trying to retrieve profile or email from user lightning component was not saving it is somewhat similar to LWC. I tried the LWC recipe from github in fresh dev org same issue.